# More number of spheres increasing glTF file size

Tags: modeling, export, gltf

I am new to blender, I'm trying to build a block which has 100s of spheres(you can say molecules of metal block) and continously vibrating. Currently I am using around 100 molecules for just 1/4th of metal block and the exported(.glb) file size is few MBs if I add more spheres to cover the entire block file size will be even more.

Is there any better way to optimize the spheres keeping their size and animation same.

[image]

Comment: i have never tried it but Blender has Linked duplicates that do not create complete copies but just links https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/duplication.html#linked-duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Linked Duplicates are optimized by Blender better in recent versions (see [glTF-Blender-IO#950](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/950)), and should avoid duplicating vertex data in these cases.

If you find that Blender (or other software, for that matter) is still duplicating data in your glTF file for some reason, there are a few optimization tools that can clean up the glTF file after export as well.

1. [gltfpack CLI tool](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer/tree/master/gltf) overhauls a glTF file, simplifying and optimizing lots of things. Probably the most comprehensive optimization tool here.
2. [gltf-transform CLI or JavaScript tool](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/cli.html) provides a `dedup` command to detect and fix duplicated data. An additional `instance` command applies the glTF `EXT_mesh_gpu_instancing` extension, which can further optimize the rendering of these types of models, but not all glTF viewers support the extension.